# headmeta in zend..?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Im a beginer to zend.I want to know what this code means...?

```
$this->view->headMeta()->setName('robots',"INDEX,FOLLOW");
$this->view->headMeta()->setName('googlesite-verification',"_3vNeAL1YnjfuONQpwHEIxrB1t_f70Vv7PRiDAA2DxI");
$this->view->headMeta()->setName('msvalidate.01',"639F7E66580EC5D78CFC78B18DF13CEC");
$this->view->headMeta()->setName('y_key',"1db0ae435e4195a0");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend_View_Helper_HeadMeta is a view helper.

> The HTML `<meta>` element is used to provide meta information about your HTML document -- typically keywords, document character set, caching pragmas, etc. Meta tags may be either of the 'http-equiv' or 'name' types, must contain a 'content' attribute, and can also have either of the 'lang' or 'scheme' modifier attributes.

API
http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.6/Zend_View/Helper/Zend_View_Helper_HeadMeta.html

Usage http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.6/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headmeta